# SVN Client that plays nicely with content edited in a machine without the client

Tags: svn

Hey, I'm looking for a SVN client but before everyone jumps in saying Toirtoise, etc, I got a "feature request" that the SVN needs to handle.

So here's the catch, I have 3 machines, 2 of them I can install the client and one of them I can't given machine/company policies on it, so I need to be able to zip the content from one of the two machines that I have the client installed to the clientless machine, be able to edit it and then zip and send it back to the machines with a client and commit the source code, Tortoise doesn't play nice with that setup and quite often forces you to solve tons of conflicts and it's as annoying as it could be.

I'm developing an ASP.NET (C#) website, I've tried AnkhSvn, it's OK but it doesn't work all too well and you have very few options about folders outside your Visual Studio solution, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

svn doesn't care how the files got edited.  You should be able to move files from a working tree, edit them, move them back, then check them in.

Don't take the .svn directory if you can help it, and be careful about OS differences.  When you edit the files, are you changing the line endings?

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar situation. I've a system running Ubuntu (SVN 1.5) and another running XP (SVN 1.6).

What I do to solve SVN version problems is to share the code on a network drive. Then I can copy it around, do changes and commit from my XP machine (if that's the case).

Also make sure that the line endings are the same in the different code editors that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done in the past.

If I'm planning to work offline, I'll copy the directory containing the working copy to my laptop.  I then search the directory for any _svn and .svn directories and remove them from my laptop.  (I use the .Net workaround, hence the _svn)

When I return to my desk I just copy the files over the ones in my working copy and then commit.

If there is a chance that the working copy was updated as well as the one on my laptop, I copy the laptop files to a new directory and then run winmerge to make sure that all of the correct changes are made.  Then I commit the working copy.

Comment: I'll try to delete the .svn folders tonight and I'll let you know if it works :) Thanks.